# Why flag weight of 749

Tags: support, flagging

I was browsing through the [badges](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/badges) page and I noticed that to get a `Marshall` badge, you need to have

> Achieved a flag weight of 749 by reviewing and flagging appropriately

Is there a specific reason for this?

Comment: I've flagged this to boost my flag weight.

Comment: oooh interesting... can I flag it too to increase my own flag weight?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103423/why-is-the-marshal-badge-awarded-at-a-flag-weight-of-749-and-not-at-750

Comment: [Flag weight is gone.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84859/we-dont-need-to-see-flag-weight) Good riddance!

Answer (score 3):

Flag weight was meant to rise asymptotically towards 750, but the formula in fact overreaches and makes 750 attainable.

For more information, see the [flag weight FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80170/what-is-flag-weight), and other [flag weight discussions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flag-weight) on the main meta.

Note that it takes [566 helpful flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97890/how-many-flags-to-reach-750-flag-weight/103161#103161) (assuming none declined) to reach 749. At the moment no one has even raised the 40 that it takes to get to 500 (the [Deputy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/badges/65/deputy) badge) on this site. By that time the flag weight rules may well have changed anyway.